# Wrap a "frame" image around another image with ImageMagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

I'm looking for a quick way to generate mobile screenshots, where a screenshot is wrapped with a phone frame image having transparent background. So I want to create a new image by combining these two images.

Not all screenshots are the same size, so the phone frame image also needs to be scaled horizontally or vertically to match the dimensions of the screenshot.

I know there's the `composite` tool, but not sure if there's any specific support or technique for wrapping in this way.

Comment: I would say it would be simpler to resize the screen shot to fit the frame. I would use convert as it has more options than composite. The code could vary depending on what IM version your are using and programing language. For instance with V7 you could probably do everthing with one command whereas in V6 you may need an intermediate variable.

Comment: Do you have the phone frames available? Are there tens of different sizes/types? What happens when the image is upright/portrait but the frame is horizontal/landscape - a distorted image will look weird as will a gap in the phone screen. Are you on Windows, or a decent OS?

Comment: Agree, the source image could be resized first. There's usually just a few px variation, so the aspect ratio won't be distorted much, but it would still mess up the wrapping.

Comment: Mark - only profile and almost all same sizes. I'm on a decent OS (Ubuntu)

Comment: Could you provide one or two sample phones and a sample screenshot so that I don’t spend ages working something out only to find I have misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: Made a quick frame here https://imgur.com/a/lktyz (via http://www.designbolts.com/2016/10/19/free-vector-google-pixel-mockup-in-ai-eps-format/) and could be any screenshot such as  ttps://www1-lw.xda-cdn.com/files/2017/05/Screenshot_20170516-195120.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you would have to get your screen image (in this case I cropped it from your pair of cell phone images). Then resize to fill the hole in the cell phone frame (or a tad larger), then use convert ... -composite to compose the resize image behind the frame.

Screen Image:

[image]

Cell Phone Frame:

[image]

```
convert frame.png \( screen.png -resize 230x328^ \) -gravity center -geometry +0-2 -compose dstover -composite result.png
```

[image]

See:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert